# How to prove the convexity of $\operatorname{Tr}(WLW^T)$, where $L$ is a Laplacian matrix?

Tags: convex-analysis, trace

How to prove the convexity of

$$f (W) = \operatorname{Tr}(WLW^T)$$

where $L$ is a (positive semidefinite) Laplacian matrix?

I need to prove this to build a convex function for optimization in a machine learning method.

Comment: That is just a number, numbers are not convex. What function are you talking about $W \mapsto $, $L \mapsto $, $(W,L) \mapsto$?

Comment: Thanks copper, the function is about $f(W)=\operatorname{Tr}(WLW^T)$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(W) = \sum_k e_k^T W L W^T e_k$, it suffices to show that 
$g(W) = v^T W L W^T v $ is convex for any $v$.

Since $L \ge 0$, we have $2 x^Ty \le x^TLx+y^TLy $ for any $x,y$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
g(t W_1+(1-t)W_2) &=& t^2g(W_1)+(1-t)^2g(W_2)+2t(1-t)vW_1LW_2^T v \\
&\le& t^2g(W_1)+(1-t)^2g(W_2)+t(1-t)(g(W_1)+g(W_2)) \\
&=& t g(W_1)+(1-t)g(W_2)
\end{eqnarray}
and so $g$, and hence $f$, is convex.

A simpler way is to note that since $L \ge 0$ we can write $L=C^TC$ and so
$g(v) =\|CW^Tv\|^2$. Since $W \mapsto CW^T v$ is linear, $\|\cdot\|$ is convex and so $W \mapsto \|CW^Tv\|$ is convex. Since $t \mapsto t^2$ is convex and nondecreasing on $t \ge 0$ we see that $g$ is convex.

An even simpler way is to let $\phi(t) = g(W+tH)$ and compute
$\phi''(0) = 2 v^THLH^Tv $ which is $\ge 0$, since $L \ge 0$.
Then $t \mapsto g(t W_1+(1-t)W_2)$ is convex and hence so is $g$.